# Can't use OAuth2.0 on xamarin android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

OnCreate:

```
MainActivity (auth.GetUI (this));

Login();
```

```html
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

I installed xamarin.OAuth on nuget. and here is code :

```html
public void Login()
  {
   auth = new OAuth2Authenticator (
    clientId: "3b5a1",
    scope: "",
    authorizeUrl: new Uri ("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize"),
    redirectUrl: new Uri ("http://Instagramcallback.com/callback")
   
   );

   auth.Completed+= (sender, e) => {
    //DismissViewController(true,null);

    if(e.IsAuthenticated)
    {
     
    }
    else
    {
     // errors be showing at here
    }
   };
  }
```

Fail: I don't see any popup be show on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get your `auth` object, you are not showing the login UI (see the guide in the link below):

#### On iOS:

```
PresentViewController (auth.GetUI (), true, null);
```

(The GetUI method returns `UINavigationControllers` on iOS)

#### On Android

The following code to present the UI from OnCreate:

```
StartActivity (auth.GetUI (this));
```

#### Getting Started:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/GettingStarted.md